# Why this form submit allways... Validation javascript doesnt work

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This form allways submit, never javascript stop with the errors. What is wrong?

thanks in advance ;)

I put the onsubmit return valida(this).... and the javascript code seems well

```
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/altaanuncio" onSubmit="return valida(this)">


function valida(f) {

        if (f.marca.selectedIndex==0){
            $('#errores').html('Seleccione la marca.');
            f.marca.focus();
         return false;
    }

        else if(f.garantia.value == ""){
            $('#errores').html('Introduzca meses de garantía');
            f.garantia.focus();
                return false;
        }

        else if(f.pvpofertado.value == ""){
            $('#errores').html('Introduzca el precio del coche');
            f.pvpofertado.focus();
                return false;

        }

     return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put valida(this) instead of return valida(f) ?

Comment: Ok what server-side language/framework are you using?

Comment: @lc2817 in plain JS it of course MUST be `return valida(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to call **jQuery functions** on **plain JS elements**. Try this:

```
// When the DOM is ready:
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Attach submit event listener to form (== onSubmit)
    $('#formulario').submit(function(event) {

        // Get the jQuery object for the 'marca' field:
        var marca = event.target.children('#marca');

        if (marca.attr('selectedIndex') === 0) {
            $('#errores').text('Seleccione la marca.');
            marca.focus(); // <--this now works because it's a jQuery object.
            event.preventDefault(); // instead of return false;
        }
    });
});

<form id="formulario" />
```

Comment: Ah, @mplungjan beat me to it.

Comment: I know whats happen. I HAVE AJAX SUBMIT!!!! Then it submit always, are there any mode of call the function and stop the submit?

Comment: But I have a very slow connection today so it takes me forever to fix typos ;)

Comment: [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) should stop the submit event from performing its usual action (i.e. submitting the form via the regular way). If you're using AJAX to submit anyway, this should probably be at the top of your submit() event handler. See @mplungjan's answer.

Comment: @PPvG what would be the most elegant way of not continuing the validation after each focus? return false?

Comment: @mplungjan `return` would be the right way to return from a function 'prematurely', so it could be used to prevent the AJAX call in case of error. Alternatively, to make it more explicit, it could also be placed in an `else` block. If @Rom does decide to use `return`, it's probably wise to put `preventDefault` at the top to make sure the form isn't submitted if you're returning early because of errors.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously use jQuery so use jQuery all the way

There are validation plugins to be found here: http://zoomzum.com/useful-jquery-form-validation/

And post here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#formulario").bind("submit",function(e) {
    var f = this; // or $(this) but then you need to test .val() and use find() or children
    if (f.marca.selectedIndex==0){
       $('#errores').html('Seleccione la marca.');
       f.marca.focus();
       e.preventDefault();
    }
.
.
.
.
   }
   $.post($(this).attr('action'),$(this).serialize(),
     success: function( response )  {
       console.log( response );
     }
   });
   e.preventDefault(); // cancel the actual submit       

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="formulario" id="formulario" method="POST" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/altaanuncio">
```

Comment: I know whats happen. I HAVE AJAX SUBMIT!!!! Then it submit always, are there any mode of call the function and stop the submit?

Comment: Sure. Please see update. I will add an example but my internet is SLOOOW right now